# Relation Between TableViewController and Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, swift2

In my `tableviewcell` I have a `UIImageView`. This `ImageView` is used to present the user a thumbnail of a recorded video. Below is how I am setting up the `ImageView`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var thumbImageView: UIImageView! {
    didSet {

            let videoUrl = NSURL(string: Link to Video )

            var thumbImage: UIImage?
            let asset = AVAsset(URL: videoUrl!)
            let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let time = CMTimeMake(asset.duration.value / 3, asset.duration.timescale)

                if let cgImage = try? assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil) {
                    thumbImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
                    print("Got Thumb")

                    self.thumbImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
                }
        }
}
```

In my `TableViewCell` I also have:

```
var URL: String? {
    didSet {
        print(URL!)
    }
}
```

In my `TableView` I am calling the Parse Database where I have stored the links of videos users have saved on My S3 server. In the `CellForRowAtIndexPath`method I am using the PFObject to provide urls to my URL variable:

```
cell.URL = Some URL
```

What I would like to have work is:

```
let videoURL = NSURL(string: self.URL!)
```

but I am getting nil when I run the code with URL passed to the thumbImageView. Is there another way I should be setting this up?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to move your `didSet` code from the `thumbImageView` to the `URL` property so it will load a image whenever the URL changes.

Currently, your code wont be run at the correct time since `imageView` will only be set when the cell is loaded from the storyboard/xib.

Comment: Such a simple solution! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At the time your thumbImageView outlet is set, it doesn't mean the you are fully initialized so you cannot be referencing self. That the reason why you are getting nil. Read up on  in swift.